# Shouldn't an object orbit and not spin when it first translated and then rotated?

Tags: transformation

I understand that the transform order matters, but I don't understand why the object in [this](https://youtu.be/HHmca-Vom1M) tutorial on minute [7:00](https://youtu.be/HHmca-Vom1M?t=464) spins and not orbits.

Line [156](https://youtu.be/HHmca-Vom1M?t=456) applies rotation and then translation on Model matrix `MathHelper::matrixMul4x4(M, transMatrix, rotYMatrix)`.
My understanding is that when rotation around Y is first applied, it sets a new frame, as shown in figure 2. After that, moving by -1 unit along Z should have been happened along new Z, as shown in image 3. This means that the object should orbit and not spin. What am I missing here?

[image]